# Failed to lazily instantiate a HashMap

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have next error:

`Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: my.shop.common.fliPusto.origins.User.spectatingBooks, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

I'm tryed initialize Map with `Hibernate.initialize()` and `myObject.getMyMap().size()`, but both of them throws exception.

My class with HashMap:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

...

@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@CollectionTable(name = "spectatingBooks", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"user_id"))
@MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "book_id")
@Column(name = "lastChapter")
private Map<Book, Long> spectatingBooks = new HashMap<Book, Long>();
}
```

When I changing fetch type from Lazy to Eager all work fine, but i think it's wrong way.

My class class that trying to add some books:

```
@Transactional
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, 
UserDetailsServiceImplInterface {

...

@Transactional
public Boolean addBookmark(User user, Long bookId) {
    Optional<Book> book = bookRepository.findById(bookId);

    if (book.isPresent()) {
        Hibernate.initialize(user);
        int size = user.getSpectatingBooks().size();    <--Exception
        user.getSpectatingBooks().put(book.get(), 
        Integer.toUnsignedLong(0));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
}
```

Is there exist any way to instantiate a HashMap Lazily or it will work only with Fetch.Eager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by getting user through `userRepository`, not `@AuthenticationPrinciple` but maybe there exist another way?

```
@Transactional
public Boolean addBookmark(Long userId, Long bookId) {
    Optional<Book> book = bookRepository.findById(bookId);
    Optional<User> userOp = userRepository.findById(userId);

    if (book.isPresent() && userOp.isPresent()) {
        User user = userOp.get();
        int size = user.getSpectatingBooks().size();
        user.getSpectatingBooks().put(book.get(), Integer.toUnsignedLong(0));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```